# HTML5 input text pattern

Tags: regex, html

I'm trying to use a pattern on an html5 input text.
This textbox **should allow** all the characters and number, both lowercase and uppercase and a `maxLenght` of 16, but **NOT** the special characters.

i tried this pattern, but it doesn't work (if i miss some character fell free to pointing it out):

```
[^!\£$%&/()=?^*§#@_:,;.-+-/|]*
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT"
       pattern="[^!\£$%&/()=?^*§#@_:,;.-+-/|]*" maxLenght='16' value="">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<span class="result"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("form").on("submit", function (evt){
  $(".result").html('ok');
  evt.preventDefault;
})
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avNKMm?editors=101

any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can the field be empty? Do you really want to allow spaces/tabs, too?

Comment: Yes, spaces and tabs are fine

Comment: thanks @stribizhev i edited my question with the snippet in the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex as

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{0,16}
```

**Demo**

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(evt) {
  $(".result").html('ok');
  evt.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{0,16}" maxLength='16' value="">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<span class="result"></span>
```

**[Explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/mO3vH7/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Try just `pattern="[A-Za-z]"` as the pattern only shows allowed characters

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have a typo in `maxLenght`. Change to `maxlength` so that it could work correctly.

You should try to use a whitelist approach rather than a blacklist one. Define what you allow:

> all the characters and number, both lowercase and uppercase

That means, `[a-zA-Z\d]` and

> and a maxLenght of 16

You should be aware of the fact that `pattern` attribute regex is anchored by default, so we can safely use `{1,16}` (a [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) matching 1 to 16 occurrences of the preceding subpattern).

To disallow empty value, use `required` attribute.

So, I would recommend:

```
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT"
   pattern="[a-zA-Z\d\s]{1,16}" required maxlength='16' value="">
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^       ^^^
```

[Updated PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbWRdG?editors=101)

```js
$("form").on("submit", function (evt){
  $(".result").html('ok');
  evt.preventDefault;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT"
       pattern="[a-zA-Z\d\s]{1,16}" required maxlength='16' value="">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<span class="result"></span>
```

Comment: Isn't it `maxlength`, not `maxLength`?

Comment: @torazaburo: It looks like the case is irrelevant: [*Attribute names for HTML elements may be written with any mix of lowercase and uppercase letters that are a case-insensitive match for the names of the attributes given in the HTML elements section of this document; that is, attribute names are case-insensitive*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#case-insensitivity). But you are right.